# MS CRM- Want to customize queue lookup in MS CRM 365 based on User Level

Tags: dynamics-crm

Once I am going to add any item in the queue then I want to see only specific queues in the below lookup not all the queues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to filter out the wanted queues like user queues.

1. You can disable/delete the user queues once it is created using plugin/WF (we were doing this long time back in 2011 version days). Even timely cleanup job is fine, till then rename/append it with “zzz_donotuse” - it can be filtered out/ignored
2. Queue lookup view filter can be modified to accommodate the list only you want to see. Normally deactivated queues won’t display

Edit: I read your question again. Seems like yours is a special request like filtering based on user. For that you may need a custom HTML page to apply logic.

Comment: Thank you very much Arun for your valuable inputs. Not sure how much time it will take to write logic for custom HTML. Right now I have written a plugin, in which first of all I am checking the logged in user security level and based on this I am checking if he/she is clicking on designated queue, otherwise I throw an exception that "you are not authorized to assign items to this queue". But I was thinking that there might be a solution to show selected queue in the lookup which makes tasks really easy.